# $e^{g(z)} = f(z)$ for holomorphic function defined on an open set

Tags: complex-analysis

The full problem:

$f: H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $H$ is an open set and $f$ is holomorphic . For $f(x) \ne 0$ show that there is a neighbourhood $ G \subset H$ of $x$  so that $h: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $e^{h(z)} = f(z)$ for all $ z\in G$

I'm honestly not quite sure where to start here. I'd be happy if someone could at least tell me what theorems I should utilize because the problem doesn't stem from the textbook I'm currently reading so I'm not a 100% positive that I already know everything I need to know in order to reasonably approach this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you familiar with covering spaces in topology?

Comment: Hint: Try the inverse function theorem (applied to $\exp$, to first prove that it is a local diffeomorphism).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm not familiar with covering spaces. As for the inverse theorem. Does it follow pretty much only from that or do I need much else? Because in about 1-2 pages I'll reach the theorem so I'll just revisit the problem when I get there.

Comment: yes, it follows almost immediately. Pretty much all we're trying to do here is show that $\exp$ is locally invertible, so that you can talk about the inverse function $\log$ (again defined only in a "small" open set around $f(x)$). Because when you see $e^{h(z)} = f(z)$, what you really want to do is to write $h(z) = \log(f(z))$.  So, the inverse function theorem allows you to justify this step locally.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that $H$ is simply, what you want to prove is Corollary 6.17 in the book
Function of one complex variable  - Jhon B. Conway